# Computational method for finding edge states?

Tags: computational-physics, topological-insulators

I am actually interested to learn how to calculate edge states  in 1D topological systems using computational methods,

Q. can anyone tell me which method is best suited and easy to calculate edge spectrums and winding numbers especially for interacting systems?

and I was also going through one paper and I have found following graph for 1 D system

[image: the figure shows the spectrum for finite chain L=64]

The above figure shows the edge spectrum for finite chain of length L=64 where y-axis show energy

Q. can anyone tell me which method is used here to obtain edge spectrum like above?

Comment: That figure is certainly obtained through diagonalizing a non-interacting fermion Hamiltonian. The computational method is just numerically finding the eigenvalues.